# Can you POST to a PUT signedUrl?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I generated a signed Url using the PUT verb and I want to know can you POST data to a PUT signed url to upload objects to Google Cloud buckets?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you sign a URL specifying a "PUT" verb, you must make a PUT request.

There is a way to upload objects using signatures and a POST verb, but it's not with signed URLs. It's with signed policy requests, which are a similar but more complex concept: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#usage_and_examples

With policy documents, you specify several rules about a POST upload, base64 the policy, and then create a signature for that policy. The POST request must include both the policy and its signature. It's designed for use with web forms, like so:

```
<form action="http://travel-maps.storage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="key" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="travel-maps">
<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
<input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="1234567890123@developer.gserviceaccount.com">
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="bucket-owner-read">
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://www.example.com/success_notification.html">
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTAtMDYtMTZUMTE6MTE6MTFaIiwNCiAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICJrZXkiLCAiIiBdLA0KICB7ImFjbCI6ICJidWNrZXQtb3duZXItcmVhZCIgfSwNCiAgeyJidWNrZXQiOiAidHJhdmVsLW1hcHMifSwNCiAgeyJzdWNjZXNzX2FjdGlvbl9yZWRpcmVjdCI6ICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3Nfbm90aWZpY2F0aW9uLmh0bWwiIH0sDQogIFsiZXEiLCAiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlL2pwZWciIF0sDQogIFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLCAwLCAxMDAwMDAwXQ0KICBdDQp9">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="BSAMPLEaASAMPLE6SAMPLE+SAMPPLEqSAMPLEPSAMPLE+SAMPLEgSAMPLEzCPlgWREeF7oPGowkeKk7J4WApzkzxERdOQmAdrvshKSzUHg8Jqp1lw9tbiJfE2ExdOOIoJVmGLoDeAGnfzCd4fTsWcLbal9sFpqXsQI8IQi1493mw=">

<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```